# Windows Server 2003 Process Monitoring and Logging

Tags: process, windows-server-2003, monitoring

Can anyone recommend software to monitor and log the processes (CPU, RAM, Disk IO, etc) on a Windows 2003 Server (Like Windows Sysinternals Process Explorer, but with logging)?

We have a server that appears to be healthy - CPU is not over used, RAM usage is acceptable, disk activity isn't huge - when we do spot checks. But the users are reporting that the application that is hosted on this box performs very slowly intermittently. I would like to be able to log the processes over a week and see if I can spot any problems.

The box does run 2 instances of SQL (an Express and a full version of 2005) - could this be a problem?

Thanks for your suggestions...

Comment: Perfmon comes to mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) does logging.

Comment: You really want to filter the right processes, but I am sure that is implied here.  If you do not, you will be sorry like me so many times. Procmon saves a metric ton of data. I love it, but it is still an elephant.

Comment: You're right, I should have mentioned it, so +1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I'll take another look at Process Monitor.

Answer (score 2):

(@joeqwerty really deserves any rep I get for this one...)

The built in "Performance Monitor" (PerfMon) tool is exactly what you're looking for. Using PerfMon to generate logs that are then parsed by an analysis tool (like, say, [Performance Analysis of Logs (PAL)](http://pal.codeplex.com/)) can give you rafts of information.

@SamCogan write a [nice article for this year's SysAdvent](http://sysadvent.blogspot.com/2010/12/day-4-make-sense-of-perfmon-with-pal.html) that can get you started. Once you embrace PerfMon and get familiar with it you'll fall in love (and you'll gripe that other OS's don't have the "extensible performance counters" functionality that NT does).